# Matplotlib fill between different shape plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to fill with color space between two of my plots (plots are made by using `plt.plot()`). The problem is that, data for this plots, consists of different number of records, so when I try to do `plt.fill_between()` I receive an error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (36,) (21,)`

My data are in dataframe. I can partially acomplish what I want, using this code:

```
plt.fill(
    np.append(data1['x_values'], data2['x_values'][::-1]),
    np.append(data1['y_values'], data2['y_values'][::-1]),
    color="tab:gray",
)
```

But I also need to use `where` condition which is a parameter only in `plt.fill_between()`. How do I accomplish it?

**EDIT**

The plot lines are crossing each other, so ultimately I would like to be able to do something like: `where data1['y_values'] > data2['y_values]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what youre looking for:

```
x_all = np.append(data1['x'], data2['x'][::-1])
y_all = np.append(data1['y'], data2['y'][::-1])

# set condition
y_idxs = np.where(y_all < 5)[0] 

# assign the right values to your new vectors
new_x, new_y = [x_all[idx] for idx in y_idxs], [y_all[idx] for idx in y_idxs]

plt.fill_between(new_x, new_y)
```

#### Edit:

With your new condition `data1['y_values'] > data2['y_values']`

```
y_idxs = [i for i,x in enumerate(data1['y_values'] if len(data1['y_values']) < len(data2['y_values']) else data2['y_values']) if data1['y_values'][i] > data2['y_values'][i]]
new_x, new_y = [x_all[idx] for idx in y_idxs], [y_all[idx] for idx in y_idxs]
plt.fill_between(new_x, new_y)
```

Comment: It kinda works, but i need other type of WHERE clause (I added an edit), Sorry I should say that earlier